# Creating custom Gradle PlugIn, but cannot compile it: "Unresolved reference: sourceSets"

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am writing a custom Gradle plugin to configure our common Kotlin build settings,
which includes creating an integrationTest sourceSet.  I created a simple Kotlin project
to ensure that I had everything correct in a build.gradle.kts file before translating it
into the custom plugin project.  I am getting a compilation error in the plugin:

"Unresolved reference: sourceSets"

I think that the issue may be because I am trying to access the sourceSet in the plugin in an incorrect manner.  I saw some references online about using

the<SourceSetContainer>()

rather than how I am accessing the sets, below.  However, I cannot seem to get this to work in the custom plugin...compilation error.

I'd appreciate your help!

[image]

[image]

```
class CscKotlinPlugin: Plugin<Project> {

    private lateinit var javaPluginExtension: JavaPluginExtension

    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        with(project) {
            javaPluginExtension = project.extensions.getByType(JavaPluginExtension::class.java)
            configureBuild()
            . . .
```

```
    private fun Project.configureBuild() {
        val implementation = configurations.getByName("implementation")
        val integrationTestImplementation =
            configurations.getByName("integrationTestImplementation").also { it.extendsFrom(implementation) }

        val runtimeOnly = configurations.getByName("runtimeOnly")
        val integrationTestRuntimeOnly =
            configurations.getByName("integrationTestRuntimeOnly").also { it.extendsFrom(runtimeOnly) }

        with(javaPluginExtension) {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
            withJavadocJar()
            withSourcesJar()

            with(sourceSets) {
                val main = getByName("main").let { main ->

                    create("integrationTest") { sourceSet ->
                        sourceSet.compileClasspath += main.output
                        sourceSet.runtimeClasspath += main.output

                        sourceSet.resources.srcDir("src/integrationTest/resources")
                        sourceSet.java { sourceDirectorySet ->
                            sourceDirectorySet.srcDir("src/integrationTest/java")
                            sourceDirectorySet.srcDir("src/integrationTest/kotlin")
                        }
                    }
                }

                val test = findByName("test")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at your `with` nesting. I believe `sourceSets` is a member of `Project`, not `JavaPluginExtension`. I'd say generally that a bit less use of `with` will make your code more readable and easier to debug overall.

Comment: Hello and thank you for replying.  I've added two images to the posting that show the sourceSet doesn't seem to be available on the Project receiver, but it does exist in the JavaPluginExtension.  So, I am hoping for more ideas about this issue.

Comment: I copied the 'the' Gradle plugin extension from: 

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/kotlin-dsl/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/kotlin/dsl/ProjectExtensions.kt

and added it to my plugin source file.  I used it to get the sourceSets from the Project, and the issue seems to have been resolved...  

val sourceSets = project.the<JavaPluginConvention>(JavaPluginConvention::class).sourceSets


At least, it compiles...  I need to see whether it works and then figure out why! :P

Comment: not really an answer to your question, but adding sourcesets is a perfect example of using convention plugins. In stead of putting all the configuration in a single plugin, if you put your parts into separate (convention or custom plugins) you can mix and match.
A convention plugin is basically a partial gradle script that you load in another gradle script and is usually used to configure other plugins or basic stuff like adding sourcesets with related tasks (for instance for integration tests).

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce this problem on my machine... 

Make sure that you're compiling your code against Gradle API 7.1+, because `sourceSets` [getter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#getSourceSets--) was added there recently; maybe sources used by IDEA are mismatched with the actual dependency used for compilation?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!  Actually, I prefer stand-alone plugins since they can be easily reused with our other projects...  Just add the dependency and go...  Unfortunately, for this project, I ran out of time with this stand-alone and used the conventions approach.  I am going to continue to tweak the stand-alone until I get it to work and then will merge the convention code into it. Михаил, I am using 7.1.1 and Kotlin 1.5.30-M1.  I tried a few variations, but to no avail. :(. Thanks, again!